# get last insert id when using Activerecord

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord

For Sqilte3 C API, I would use `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`. How to  get this id when using ActiveRecord after insert a new record? I use following way to insert a new record :

```
Section.new |s|
     s.a = 1
     s.b = 2
     #I expected the return value of save to be the last_insert_id, but it is NOT
     s.save   
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'save' method returns true or false based on if saving was successful or not
try smth like:

```
new_section = Section.new do |s|
    s.a = 1
    s.b = 2
    s.save   
end

p new_section
```

it should print all fields you set manually plus any automatically filled values, including last_insert_id being usually the record 'id'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've used the ActiveRecord default field name to hold the primary key, then

```
s.id
```

will hold the id of the record you've just saved.